# How to check if a string contains time expression in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to make a caldendar just like google cal.

In google calendar, when one types in **"2pm dinner"** or **"2:00pm dinner"** or **"14:00pm dinner"** the system could tell the time entered and render the event starting at that time.

Also if I type **"2pm-3pm dinner"** or **"14:00-15:00 dinner"**, the system can know the length of the event.

So my question is, how to construct a function to filter out the starting time and length using javascript or jquery?

Comment: You can probably use indexOf to check for specific things. You can be pretty smart about this i.e. if there is a colon you know the time is specific, if there is a dash you know there is probably a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex eg:
`/(\d+)(pm|am) /` for 2pm dinner kind of format...
`/(\d+)(pm|am)-(\d+)(pm|am)/` for 2pm-3pm kind of format

`str.match(regex)` will give you array of captured parts in the regex
e.g.
`"2pm-3pm dinner".match(/(\d+)(pm|am)-(\d+)(pm|am)/);` will give you `["2pm-3pm ", "2", "pm", "3", "pm"]`